# Creating Multiple Alarms at once through AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, alarm

I'm trying to create multiple alarms in AWS CloudWatch by using the CLI. The bold items in my command are changeable, how do reformat the command to enable enter create multiple alarm at once?

> aws cloudwatch put-metric-alarm --alarm-name
>   **UnreservedConcurrentExecutions-testing** --alarm-description "Alert when 1 **UnreservedConcurrentExecutions** in 5 minutes period"
>   --metric-name **UnreservedConcurrentExecutions** --namespace AWS/Lambda --statistic Sum --period 300 --threshold 1
>   --comparison-operator GreaterThanThreshold  --dimensions "Name=**FunctionName**,Value=**testing**" --evaluation-periods 1
>   --alarm-actions arn:xxxxxx

Comment: `put-metric-alarm` will let you to add only one alarm per request. You have to make multiple cli requests to add multiple alarms.

Comment: Thank you! I wish there was a way to do this for multiple alarms at once.

Comment: Need to write a loop.